# icon specified in the info.plist not found in the top level app wrapper

Tags: ios, icons, plist

I'm trying to distribute my application and I get the following errors.

icon specified in the info.plist not found in the top level app wrapper: AppIcon-140x40
icon specified in the info.plist not found in the top level app wrapper: AppIcon-160x60

I don't even know what icons these dimensions are referring to. I've read several posts about this issue and most answers point to renaming or moving the files the error references. The problem is I don't have these files anywhere in my project.

I've cleaned the build, checked my plist for any reference of these and there is nothing.

I'm going nuts, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked your app's info.plist file? There should be a row something line "App-Icons" of array type. There we provide name of png icons files of different sizes. check if those entries exists there.